# C# Multithreading - wait for method to finish before running it again

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a method that looks like this:

```
while(intVariable < 4))
        {
            DoSomeStuff();

            if (intVariable == 3)
            {
                FinalDecide();
            }

            if (rollCounter < 3)
            {
                Decide(args);
            }
            intVariable++;
        }
```

The method Decide() runs 32 Threads and I want to make sure that before loop starts Decide() second time, the first time finishes

Inside Decide I have something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Prepare));
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start(i);
        }

        runner = new System.Threading.Thread(WaitforThreads);
        runner.IsBackground = true;
        runner.Start();
```

Even though I wait for those 32 threads to complete inside this run of Decide method, the code continues and fires Decide method second time before the first one finishes which causes bugs

How do I make sure that method Decide finishes WaitforThreads() method before it starts second time?

Comment: Why do you need to use 32 threads? Maybe just `Task<T>`?

Comment: How would it look like?

Comment: It hard to tell, how will it look like without having a reproducible sample and `Decide` and `Prepare` methods. The reason of using a 32 threads is completely unclear as well

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on `lock`.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and lacks any evidence that you tried anything specific, never mind clarity about what _specifically_ you need help with. That said, one approach involves: `Task.Run()` for each of the 32 work items, `Task.WhenAll()` for the `Decide()` method to await the work items, and making `Decide()` itself `async` and awaiting it in the calling loop. If you don't want to await it right away, save the returned `Task` in a local variable, and await that before calling on the next loop iteration.

Comment: *"Even though I wait for those 32 threads to complete"* <-- Can you show the code that does the waiting?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is making the Decide method return `Thread[]` of the started threads and saving this to a variable accessible from the while loop and then just join all threads before calling Decide next time:

```cs
Thread[] decideThreads = null;
while(intVariable < 4))
        {
            DoSomeStuff();

            if (intVariable == 3)
            {
                FinalDecide();
            }

            if (rollCounter < 3)
            {
                if (decideThreads != null)
                {
                    foreach (var t in decideThreads)
                        t.Join();
                }
                decideThreads = Decide(args);
            }
            intVariable++;
        }
```

Even better, you could replace the threads with `Task<T>` as was suggested in comments and then just return a `Task.WhenAll` instead of `Thread[]`. You could then use `async` to make the code more efficient:

```cs
Task decideTask = null;
while(intVariable < 4))
        {
            DoSomeStuff();

            if (intVariable == 3)
            {
                FinalDecide();
            }

            if (rollCounter < 3)
            {
                if (decideTask != null)
                    await decideTask;

                decideTask = Decide(args);
            }
            intVariable++;
        }
```

`Decide` would then do something like:

```cs
Task[] workers = new Task[32];
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            var localI = i; // to be captured in lambda
            workers[i] = new Task(() => Prepare(localI));
        }

return Task.WhenAll(workers);
```